# "Add Comment" functionality in Flex Viewer

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I want to add some kind of commenting functionality for users to leave notes on a map. I know that Esri deprecated the "add pop up" element in 2.3.1 because it didn't save. My current thinking is to direct users to create a circle feature and add their comment as an attribute using the "Edit" widget, however that seems needlessly complicated. Does anyone have a simpler solution for saving location-aware comments on the map?

Comment: Welcome to our site, @Dave, and thank you for creating such a well-posed question.

Answer (score 1):

I know I have been wanting to dig into this for weeks. But, I haven't taken the time to dig in.
 I assume you have purused the code gallery. ??
The enhanced draw and the attachment relate widgets might shortcut for you.
And in samples there is the edit tool sample.
   http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=EditTools